# Actor design for queue with a long running task

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I have a bunch of actors running which need to enqueue tasks to be processed sequentially, one at a time. I will need an actor to process the tasks on the queue. Is it ok to create one actor and pass a reference to that actor as a parameter to each job (an implicit queue)? Ex.

**Actor:**

```
class QActor extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case input => sender ! doSomething(input)
  }
}
```

**Sender**

```
val future = myQActor ? msg
Await.result(future)
```

Comment: Thread pools and Futures are all you need here, like @al32 said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using another actor and its mailbox as a queue is fine, just don't block in the sender.

Comment: No there's not, you're given a `Future`.  You can use `map`, `flatMap`, etc.  No need to block.  Or just use `pipeTo` and send the result back to `self`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks fine but with one caveat. The ask pattern (`?`) requires an implicit timeout, after which if no reply is received, the Future fails with a timeout error. If you have multiple actors all simultaneously asking your `QActor` which processes each request sequentially, it may be difficult to know what is a reasonable timeout to set. It may be better to use `myQActor ! msg` and implement a handler in `Receive` of your sender to handler the expected response.